# Updating state in React.js component leaves blank space under my page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wookmark, imagesloaded

I have a React.js component that renders a list of elements on page load, but this list can be updated with a filter that will remove certain elements from the list and save the modified list in the component's state. I managed to make this functionnality work, so the state is updated correctly.

While the elements get re-rendred correcly, less space is used when less elements are rendred. When this happens, the page's height doesn't shrink to adapt to the new size occupied by the page and leaves empty content under my footer, which is the last element of my page.

**Edit :**

I looked a bit more into this and I think React.js may not be the cause of my problem. I call a function that uses imagesLoaded and Wookmark jQuery plugins after each update of the component's state and it looks like calling this function after each state change does not work well. Is there something I should change in the called function or I should call the function at another point in time?

```
var ActivityListClass = React.createClass({
loggedInUser: {},
componentDidUpdate: function() {
    activityListImageResponsiveness(); // This is the function
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    var theActivityList = this;
    var activitiesGetListener = postal.subscribe({
        channel: "activities",
        topic: "list",
        callback: function(data, envelope) {
            var dataClone = $.extend(true, {}, data);
            dataClone.activities.shift();
            theActivityList.setState({data: dataClone.activities});
            theActivityList.loggedInUser = dataClone.loggedInUser;
        }
    });
},
getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
},
render: function() {
    var i = 0;
    var activityNodes = this.state.data.map(function(activity) {
        var currentId = i;
        i++;
        return (
            <ActivityClass key={currentId} data={activity} />
        );
    });
    return (
        <section id="listArticles">
            {activityNodes}
        </section>
    );
}
});
```

And the function called is defined like this :

```
function activityListImageResponsiveness() {
    $('#listArticles').imagesLoaded(function() {
        // Get a reference to your grid items.
        var $handler = $('#listArticles article');

        $handler.on("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", function(event) {
            if(event.originalEvent.propertyName == 'top'){
                $('#listArticles').trigger("refreshWookmark");
            }
        });

        // Prepare layout options.
        var options = {
            align: 'left',
            autoResize: true, // This will auto-update the layout when the browser window is resized.
            container: $('#listArticles'), // Optional, used for some extra CSS styling
            direction: 'left',
            fillEmptySpace: true, // Optional, fill the bottom of each column with widths of flexible height
            flexibleWidth: '16.635%',
            itemWidth: $handler.width(), // Optional, the width of a grid item
            offset: 42, // Optional, the distance between grid items
            verticalOffset: 15
        };

        var $window = $(window);
        $window.resize(function() {
            var windowWidth = $window.width(),
            newOptions = {
                flexibleWidth: '16.635%',
                itemWidth: 208
                };

            // NOTE: These values are the same as the "media queries" of the CSS file.
            if(windowWidth >= 1263){
                newOptions.flexibleWidth = '16.635%';
                newOptions.itemWidth = 208;
            } else if (windowWidth >= 1132){
                newOptions.flexibleWidth = '21.05263157894737%';
                newOptions.itemWidth = 236;
            }else if(windowWidth >= 1014){
                newOptions.flexibleWidth = '20.71713147410359%';
                newOptions.itemWidth = 208;
            }else if(windowWidth >= 852){
                newOptions.flexibleWidth = '27.99525504151839%';
                newOptions.itemWidth = 236;
            }else if(windowWidth >= 764){
                newOptions.flexibleWidth = '27.51322751322751%';
                newOptions.itemWidth = 208;
            }else if(windowWidth >= 626){
                newOptions.flexibleWidth = '42.58064516129032%';
                newOptions.itemWidth = 264;
            }else if(windowWidth >= 515){
                newOptions.flexibleWidth = '40.7843137254902%';
                newOptions.itemWidth = 208;
            }else{
                newOptions.flexibleWidth = '83.80952380952381%';
                newOptions.itemWidth = 264;
            }

        $handler.wookmark(newOptions);
    });
    // Call the layout function.
    $handler.wookmark(options);
    });
}
```

Comment: Without code, it's hard to help you. Also it's not clear to me what *"big blank space is shown under the page's HTML"* means. React doesn't produce HTML... Do you mean the browser renders blank area somewhere? What makes you think it should not do that?

Comment: @FelixKling Your last question made me question myself. I indeed wasn't 100% sure this wasn't supposed to happen. I found that Wookmark leaves behind invisible divs in the listArticles section that contains my rendered elements. I tried removing all these divs before each render with $("#listearticles .wookmark-placeholder").remove(); It looks like it's working, but renders of the component are a bit slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Wookmark leaves behind invisible divs in the listArticles section that contains my rendered elements, which explains why I had a weird blank space in the bottom of my page. I tried removing all these divs before each render with $("#listArticles .wookmark-placeholder").remove(); It looks like it's working, but renders of the component are a bit slower.

To do this, I added the componentWillUpdate function to my React component:

```
componentWillUpdate: function() {
    $("#listArticles .wookmark-placeholder").remove();
},
```